# Calling function that expect an event AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Thank you for taking the time to read my question! So I have a function in my code that gets called after a TimerEvent. Like this:

```
shootTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, shoot, false, 0, true);
private function shoot(e:Event):void
```

there is no problem with that, but what if I want to call the function shoot for something else too. like let's say

```
if(speed > 5)
shoot();
```

it doesn't work like that, can someone please explain me how to do it? Thank you a lot, in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a default for the parameter, so you can call it without an event :

```
private function shoot(e:Event = null):void
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
shootTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, shoot, false, 0, true);

private function shoot(e:Event):void
{
realShoot();
}


if(speed > 5)
{
realShoot();
}
```